# How to build CQ.Dialog from the dialog json in javascript?

Tags: javascript, aem

In javascript, I get the dialog as follow:

```
var url = CQ.HTTP.externalize(pathToDialog+".infinity.json");
var dialog = CQ.HTTP.eval(url);
```

my Question is How to convert this `dialog` to [CQ:Dialog](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/widgets-api/index.html?class=CQ.Dialog) Widget, sothat I can use CQ:Dialog Methods like find( String prop, String value ), which u can find in the [CQ5 Widget API](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/current/widgets-api/index.html?class=CQ.Dialog)

Thanks for help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the getDialog() method of [CQ.WCM](http://dev.day.com/docs/en/cq/5-5/widgets-api/index.html?class=CQ.WCM) class to get the dialog object for the url. Additionally, you can also pass a config object to perform functions like caching the dialog, looking for the dialog in the cache alone and so on.

```
var dialog = CQ.WCM.getDialog(pathToDialog + ".infinity.json");
```

Comment: This displays the error: TypeError: item.setSize is not a function

Comment: There might be an issue with the structure of your dialog. Otherwise this would work just fine. Could you post additional info regarding your dialog?

Comment: the path to my dialog was wrong :( thank you so much for your answer!!